# PHP results not displaying and no error message to go by

Tags: php, mysql

A self taught newbie here looking for advice...

I have very simple PHP query against a MySQL database that is suppose to generate a drop down menu populated with information from the MySQL database. I was wondering if based on the code included in this posting someone could steer me in the right direction or lend a suggestion as to what I should.

P.s. the MySQL database is *products* the table I am selecting from within is *products* and the column I am trying to select is *description*.

```
<?php
$adConn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "products");

$result = "SELECT * FROM products where Description order by descending";
$result = mysqli_query($adConn, $result);

echo "<select name='product'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Description'] . "'>" . $row['Description'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: now change your password

Answer (score 2):

Your `where` condition is not correct. Also look for `order by`.

Try this :

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM products where Description = 'SOME VALUE' order by SOME FIELD desc;
```

Refer this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Also you are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`.

Please don't use `mysql_*` it is deprecated and removed from PHP 7.

For mysqli : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the descriptions from your *products* table, you can change your select statement to something like this:

```
SELECT description 
FROM products
ORDER BY <column name> desc;
```

This will give you all the descriptions on your *products* table, in descending order based on a column name.  Not sure what you are trying to order by on the *products* table, but you need to add a column name to your `ORDER BY` clause.

Note - You had *description* in your `WHERE` clause, so if you are looking for a specific *description*, you could do something like this instead:

```
SELECT description
FROM products
WHERE description = 'some specific description';
```

Returns one specific *description* only, thus no need for an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basic concepts of how to make a SQL statement .

Here are some basic queries you can take a look at for example:

Simple straight forward select all:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

Select where column value equals to something:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category=foo;
```

Select and order by column ascending(`ASC`) or descending(`DESC`) order :

```
SELECT * FROM  products ORDER BY product_id DESC;
```

now lets combine them:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE product_category = foo 
ORDER BY product_id DESC;
```

It is good practice to keep all SQL functions in uppercase and column names and values in lowercase making it easy to read. Also, don't use `mysql_*` since it's deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Instead, use `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for your comments and suggestions.  This web community turned out to be pretty good.  I am glad that there are still people on the web willing to brainstorm and help a newbie!

Have a great day!